# Max attempts count

Tags: sql, sql-server

From the below table I want the result at what attempt the each Emp_ID get the value '1' from the field **value**

```
Emp_ID | Value
167    | 0
175    | 0
175    | 1
167    | 0
188    | 0
188    | 0
167    | 1
216    | 1
188    | 1
217    | 0
```

Output Should be like this:

```
Emp_ID | Attempt_Count
167    | 3
175    | 2
188    | 3
216    | 1
217    | 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  Emp_Id,
  CASE WHEN MAX(Value)>0 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END Attempt_Count
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  Emp_Id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8bbe/1). This query will return the total number of rows for each Emp_Id, if there's at least one value greater than 0. Otherwise it will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select emp_id,count(1) as Attempt_Count
from tab
group by emp_id
```